Questions About Advertising TOS on Twitter and YouTube
I was recently disabled by Facebook because I frequently posted similar content in multiple Facebook groups to advertise my services. Facebook was the only platform where I could find clients. Since being blocked, I haven't gained any new clients because my profile and all my posts on Facebook have become invisible to everyone. I already appealed, but my appeal was rejected.
I tried creating a new Facebook account four times, including using a different device, different Wi-Fi, and clearing all my browser cache beforehand, but my accounts were suspended within 8 hours each time.
I'm now trying to move on and explore other social media platforms like Twitter and YouTube. However, I've never advertised my services using video content before, so it will take some time for me to get used to it. I'm confident I can adapt, but I need to understand their Terms of Service (TOS) first to avoid being blocked again like I was on Facebook.
First of all, is it allowed to advertise on Twitter and YouTube? Based on my research, advertising is allowed on Twitter, but I'm not sure about YouTube. What about indirect advertising within educational content? For example, if I create a video about "How to Write High-Quality Articles" and include my website, phone number, and home address in the video and description for people who might want to order my article-writing services, would that be permitted?
This is the only idea I have at the moment, but I need to understand the limitations of these platforms. Specifically, is it allowed to include my website, phone number, and home address in the video and description? Are there any other TOS or risks I should be aware of when advertising my services on these platforms? Any advice or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

VTC as its really asking for opinions. Whilo knows what the OP will post.
